How to make my postgresql db case insensitive and accent sensitive?
I just found for my surprise, that some of my queries are not working because the postgresql db I created, is taking case sensitive as default for values. I'm sql server user and of course I pretend to have the same here, to be "case insensitive-accent sensitive".
In other words, the problem:
"LastName" = 'Doe' <- brings results
"LastName" = 'doe' <- does not bring results.

So 2 questions.

How to create a database with "case insensitive-accent sensitive".?
How to change an existing database to become "case insensitive-accent sensitive". (This seems impossible as per what I have investigated so far)

While trying a default setting, first testing with Locale Provider, i'm using PosgreSQL 16 at the moment, but had 0 issue to upgrade to newer versions if that is needed.


That is not possible.

in your query, replace "LastName" = 'Doe' by lower("LastName") = lower('Doe') and  "LastName" = 'doe' by lower("LastName") = lower('doe')

Have a look at non deterministic collations, including their limitations https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/10/14/nondeterministic-collations.html
